# Calling AJAX modal popup using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, modalpopupextender

I'm using a javascript function in window.onbeforeunload event to warn user when user exit the page. I want to call an AJAX modal popup instead of the default popup message window. When I try to use the modal popup window, default popup window is also showing with it (return false). Is there any way to block this default popup?? Please find my java script code below. Thanks, Justin

```
function confirmExit() {
    if (needToConfirm) {
        var optOut = 0;
        if (document.getElementById('<%= hidOptOut.ClientID%>') != null) {
            optOut = document.getElementById('<%= hidOptOut.ClientID%>').value;
        }
        if (optOut == 0 || optOut == '') {
            $find("mpe").show();
            return false
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) out of the code so that we can see it in action and help you better?

Comment: Hi Vivek, thank you so much for your reply. I think it's not possible to alter the popup in beforeunload event. Found this link from Microsoft. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx . Thanks,Justin